# MapView: draw line on route

Tags: android, android-mapview, draw, routes

I'am trying to draw a route on google's MapView. but my line is not drawed on the streets like this in screenshot

[image: Example image]

I've used this code:

```
    GeoPoint gp1;
    GeoPoint gp2 = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml").append("?origin=").append(origin)
      .append("&destination=").append(destination)
      .append("&mode=driving&sensor=true&language=de");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    xmlPaser parser = new xmlPaser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(sb.toString());
    Document doc = parser.XmlFromString(xml);
    System.out.println(doc);
    NodeList start = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_location");
    NodeList end = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_location");
    for (int intLoop = 0 ; intLoop < start.getLength() ; intLoop++){
        Element eStart = (Element) start.item(intLoop);
        Element eEnd = (Element) end.item(intLoop);
        String test = parser.getValue(eStart, "lat");
        String test2 = parser.getValue(eStart, "lng");
        if (intLoop == 0){
            gp1 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(eStart, "lat")) * 1E6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(eStart, "lng")) * 1E6));
        }else{
            gp1 = gp2;
        }
        gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(eEnd, "lat")) * 1E6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(eEnd, "lng")) * 1E6));
        ViewMap.getMap().getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp1, gp2));
    }
}
```

how can i draw the line on the street overlay?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
I'am posting this answer if someone else have the same problem.

the start- & end_location are just the main points of the route. to draw a detailed view of the route you have to use the  from the xml and parse this to geoPoint.

to do this i've used this function: [polyline to geoPoints](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java)

then you have to pass the geoPoints to your draw method.

greetings.